# EMI/UCP basic approach

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

[EMI/UCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EMI_%28protocol%29) is a protocol to communicate to SMS gateways.

I am confused how should I do in respect to network connection.

Do you open a socket for each logic bundle of data (and close it of course), or do you re-use the same socket?

How do you handle out-of-sequence responses in both cases?

My use case is send a couple of SMS with status request (submit short message), each will generate a traffic of 4 messages (a 51 operation and its ack and a 53 operation from the gateway plus the 53 ack).

If I open two sockets, may I be confident each dialog is performed on the some socket or is it a false assumption?

If I use a single socket, how I distinguish the messages from the two conversations? From the OaDC (originator address) only?

Answer (score 1):

Answering the last question: you have to match the time stamp in the Ucp51 response message (ACK). It is the field: SCTS.

The correlation id is the couple SCTS and ADC (address caller: it is the recipient cell phone).